# Debugging Snake game written in Java Swing

Tags: java, user-interface, debugging

I am having trouble making a main menu for my snake swing application. When I run the application I want to have the user be able to click the start game button and play the game. However, when I click on the start game button the card gets stuck and doesn't display the game class that extends JPanel. After tinkering I found that if I remove the game.play() method from my GameFrame class it will load the next "card" as I am using the CardLayout to display different windows. I'm not sure what it is about my play function or Game class that is causing my application to stop working. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

```
// GameFrame.java

  import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

// TODO: read up on layouts, add layout to the game
public class GameFrame{
    /**
    *
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public GameFrame() {

   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   JPanel initMenu = new JPanel();
   JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   Game game = new Game();

   frame.setSize(400, 400);
   frame.setVisible(true);
   frame.setTitle("SnEk");
   frame.add(mainPanel);

   CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

   // add cardlayout to the mainPanel which will be the container for the the other two 'cards'
   mainPanel.setLayout(cl);

  // initMenu.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

   mainPanel.add(initMenu);
   mainPanel.add(game);

   JButton startButton = new JButton("Start Game");
   initMenu.add(startButton);

   startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           cl.next(mainPanel);
       while(game.isAlive){
               game.play();
               }            
       }
       });
   }
   public static void main(String[] args){
           new GameFrame();
   }
}
```

```
// Game.java

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public int BOARD_WIDTH = 400;
    public int BOARD_HEIGHT = 400;
    // field to keep track of snake head hitting the border of the game board
    public String isOnWhichBorder = "";

    int randX = (int)(Math.random() * ((BOARD_WIDTH) + 1));
    int randY = (int)(Math.random() * ((BOARD_HEIGHT) + 1));

    Apple apple = new Apple(randX, randY, 20, 20);
    Snake snake = new Snake();

    public int[] RIGHT = new int[]{snake.getOvalHeight(), 0};
    public int[] LEFT = new int[]{-snake.getOvalHeight(), 0};
    public int[] UP = new int[]{0,-snake.getOvalHeight()};
    public int[] DOWN = new int[]{0,snake.getOvalHeight()};

    public boolean isAlive = true;

    // default snake direction vector moves to the right
    public int[] direction = RIGHT;

    public Game(){

        //setFocusable(true);
        // TODO: check where keyListener actually needs to g
        //addKeyListener(this);    
        setSize(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(apple.getIsEaten()){ 
            apple.setX((int)(Math.random() * ((BOARD_WIDTH) + 1)));
            apple.setY((int)(Math.random() * ((BOARD_HEIGHT) + 1)));
            apple.setIsEaten(false);
            snake.grow();
        }
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        for(int i = 0; i < snake.getLength(); i++){
            g.fillOval(snake.getBodyXComponent(i), snake.getBodyYComponent(i), snake.getOvalHeight(), snake.getOvalWidth());
        }
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(apple.getX(), apple.getY(), apple.getWidth(), apple.getHeight());
    }
    /*
     * @param isOnWhichBorder the isOnWhichBorder to set
     */
    public void setIsOnWhichBorder(final String isOnWhichBorder) {
        this.isOnWhichBorder = isOnWhichBorder;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(final KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // method to check if snake and apple are occupying the same point in the game board
    public boolean isCollision(Apple apple, Snake snake){
        if(((snake.getHead()[0] >= Math.abs(apple.getX() - apple.getWidth())) && (snake.getHead()[0] <= (apple.getX() + apple.getWidth()))) && ((snake.getHead()[1] >= Math.abs(apple.getY() - apple.getHeight())) && (snake.getHead()[1] <= (apple.getY() + apple.getHeight())))){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /*
     Method to determine whether or not the snake head's x and y component are occupying the same coordinate as a body part 
    */
    // TODO: change isAlive variable to isGameOver
    public boolean isSnakeEatingItself(Snake snake){ 
        // grab head of the snake
        int[] head = snake.getHead();
        // check all body segments except the head
        for(int i = 0; i < snake.getLength() - 1; i++){
            // check if head x coord and head y coord equals body x coord and head y coord equals body y coord
            if((head[0] == snake.getBodyXComponent(i)) && (head[1] == snake.getBodyYComponent(i))){
                isAlive = false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        isAlive = true;
        return false;
    }
    // TODO: remove logic from keyPressed event, this method should only set the flags and do nothing else
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch(e.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            direction = RIGHT;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            direction = LEFT;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            direction = UP;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            direction = DOWN;
            break;
        }
    }

    public void play(){

        if(snake.getHead()[0] == 0 && !(snake.getSecondComponent()[0] == 400)){
            isOnWhichBorder = "LEFT";
         }
         if((snake.getHead()[0] == BOARD_WIDTH) && !(snake.getSecondComponent()[0] == 0)){
            isOnWhichBorder = "RIGHT";
         }
         if((snake.getHead()[1] == 0) && !(snake.getSecondComponent()[1] == 400)){
            isOnWhichBorder = "BOTTOM";
         }
         if((snake.getHead()[1] == BOARD_HEIGHT) && !(snake.getSecondComponent()[1] == 0)){
            isOnWhichBorder = "TOP";
         }
        if(isCollision(apple, snake)){
            apple.setIsEaten(true);
        }
        if(isSnakeEatingItself(snake)){
            System.out.println("eating itself");
        }
        snake.slither(isOnWhichBorder, direction);
        this.setIsOnWhichBorder("");
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(final KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {

    }

}
```

```
Snake.java


// To store the snake class
// Goal of snake class: store direction, location of body parts
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Snake {
    // stores length of snake

    public static int OVAL_WIDTH = 10;
    public static int OVAL_HEIGHT = 10;

    public static String EMPTY = "";

    public int x;
    public int y;
    // arrayList holds the body elements of the snake
    public ArrayList<int[]> body = new ArrayList<>();

    public int[] directionVector = new int[]{};

    public Snake(){
        // add some initial body elements
        body.add(new int[]{100,100});
        body.add(new int[]{110,100});
        body.add(new int[]{120,100});
    }
    public int getOvalWidth(){
        return OVAL_WIDTH;
    }
    public int getOvalHeight(){
        return OVAL_HEIGHT;
    }
    public int getLength(){
        return body.size();
    }
    // method to return the head of the ArrayList representing Snake body
    public int[] getHead(){
        int xComponent = getBodyXComponent(body.size()-1);
        int yComponent = getBodyYComponent(body.size()-1);
        int[] head = new int[]{xComponent, yComponent};
        return head;
    }

    public int[] getSecondComponent(){
        return body.get(body.size()-2);
    }

    public int getBodyXComponent(int bodySegment){
        return body.get(bodySegment)[0];
    }

    public int getBodyYComponent(int bodySegment){
        return body.get(bodySegment)[1];
    }

    public void grow(){
        body.add(new int[]{this.getHead()[0] + directionVector[0], this.getHead()[1] + this.directionVector[1]});
        System.out.println("(\n");
        for(int[] part : body){
                System.out.println("( " + part[0] + "," + part[1] + ")");
            }
        }



    public void slither(String isWhichOnBorder, int[] direction){    
        // grab tail
        int[] tail = new int[]{body.get(0)[0], body.get(0)[1]};
        // logic to handle the case where the snake head is on the border of the map
        // TODO: make this conditional on the direction as well
        this.directionVector = direction;
        if(!isWhichOnBorder.equals(EMPTY)){
            System.out.println("hitting the isEmpty() statement");
            switch(isWhichOnBorder){
                case "TOP":
                    tail[1] = 0;
                    break;
                case "BOTTOM":
                    tail[1] = 400;
                    break;
                case "LEFT":
                    tail[0] = 400;
                    break;
                case "RIGHT":
                    tail[0] = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }else{
            tail[0] = getHead()[0] + direction[0];
            tail[1] = getHead()[1] + direction[1];
            System.out.println("this is head of array: " + "( " + getHead()[0] + "," + getHead()[1] + ")");
        }

        body.remove(0);
        for(int[] part : body){
            System.out.println("( " + part[0] + "," + part[1] + ")");
        }
        body.add(tail);
        System.out.println("after adding new head: ");
        for(int[] part : body){
            System.out.println("( " + part[0] + "," + part[1] + ")");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey @alexander, could you maybe simplify the code pieces a little? I'd recommend taking out all game logic and show us a minimal example of the problem where it's easy to see the one component in question (the "start game" button that's not working and nothing else). Check here for a good explanation on how to write these: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 

Also it'd be good to give us instructions on how you're running this (i.e. what are you calling on the shell or in your editor to launch this?).